# IOS Swift imagePickerController not call

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

```
class MyPage: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    @IBOutlet weak var selectImage: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.delegate = self
    }



   @IBAction func selectImage(_ sender: Any) {
            print("a")
            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary){
                print("b")
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
                imagePicker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
                self.present(imagePicker, animated: true,completion: nil)
            }
    @objc func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
                print("dismiss")
            })

            print(image)
            selectImage.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        }
}
```

If touch button print a and b and pop photoLibrary

but select Photo not call `imagePickerController`

do nothing after select photo

how to use imagepicker in swift 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `@objc` from `Delegate` method and `delegate` method is this so replace your function with this :

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
```

and get image by using this :

```
guard let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else {return}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
let imagepicker = UIImagePickerController()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.imagepicker.delegate = self
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 150, width: 100, height: 100)
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
}

@IBAction func uploadImage(_ sender : UIButton) {
    imagepicker.cameraDevice = .rear
    imagepicker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
    imagepicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    guard let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else {
        return
    }
    imageView.image = image
    print(image)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Comment: Code-only answers are frowned upon. Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what was wrong and how the answer fixes the problems.